# VM & host can't ping eachother over bridge

Tags: networking, virtualization, qemu, kvm

I have a host machine with Debian 10 & QEMU-KVM. I installed packages and rebooted:

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm virt-manager
sudo reboot
```

---

So now I want to create a bridge that will enable my virtual servers to (a) connect to network and (b) to be seen to a host machine and other computers on the network.

I read dozen of tutorials on how to do this and failed miserably every time. I had some sucess setting up bridge with (a) package `iproute2` and (b) package `virt-manager` *(ran as super user)*.

---

### Trying as a root:

By folowing [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_bridge) I set up my bridge using these commands:

```
sudo ip link add virtual_bridge type bridge
sudo ip link set dev virtual_bridge up
```

I then reset the ethernet card and connect it to the bridge as it's slave:

```
sudo ip link set dev enx24f5a2f17b27 down
sudo ip addr flush dev enx24f5a2f17b27
sudo ip link set dev enx24f5a2f17b27 up
sudo ip link set dev enx24f5a2f17b27 master virtual_bridge
```

And then I open the GUI application:

```
sudo virt-manager
```

I right click the QEMU/KVM session (`qemu:///system`) and I choose connect:

[image]

When session is connected I start creating a new virtual machine. During it's creation I come to a window asking to choose type of virtual network. There are two options. First one has suboptions while second one enables manual input of the device:

- **Host device enx24f5a2f17b27: macvtap**

  - Bridge
  - VEPA
  - Private
  - Passthrough
- **Specify shared device name**

I tried choosing suboptions offered by the first option, but when selected they, issue a warning:

> In most configurations macvtap does not work for host to guest network communication

This is not an option for me because my virtual servers will need two-way communication. This is why I choose the second option and I manualy specify my bridge `virtual_bridge`:

[image]

Then I start the virtual machine which can browse the internet and also can the host machine. Both are assigned the IP **in the same network**. But when I try to ping them ping doesn't work in any direction. Host, can't ping virtual machine and vice versa.

[image]

I can't explain this, because [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_bridge) states that bridge should be transparent like a switch and devices should therefore be able to ping eachother:

> A bridge is a piece of software used to unite two or more network
>   segments. A bridge behaves like a virtual network switch, working
>   transparently (the other machines do not need to know or care about
>   its existence).

If I check internet settings on a host:

```
ziga@ziga-laptop:~$ ip addr 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:85:08:3c:1a:59 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enx24f5a2f17b27: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virtual_bridge state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 24:f5:a2:f1:7b:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.64.100/24 brd 192.168.64.255 scope global enx24f5a2f17b27
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::26f5:a2ff:fef1:7b27/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
32: virtual_bridge: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 24:f5:a2:f1:7b:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::26f5:a2ff:fef1:7b27/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
34: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virtual_bridge state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:c4:3e:62 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.82.75/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global vnet0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2c93:eff:fea5:c52b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

From the above, I can confirm that my ethernet interface `enx24f5a2f17b27` and `vnet0` *(which was automaticaly created by virtual machine)* are both slaves to `virtual_bridge` *(note the keywords *`master virtual_bridge`*)*.

If I am honest I was expecting GUI application to also create TAP device as well but it only created `vnet0`... Is this actually a TAP device?

How can I make connection two-way?

---

### Trying as a normal user (without bridge):

I deleted `virtual_bridge` and `virtual_tap` so that everything was back to normal.

```
ziga@ziga-laptop:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:85:08:3c:1a:59 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enx24f5a2f17b27: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 24:f5:a2:f1:7b:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.64.100/24 brd 192.168.64.255 scope global enx24f5a2f17b27
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::26f5:a2ff:fef1:7b27/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I noticed that if I start `virt-manager` with `sudo` and use `qcow2` image that image will become owned by `root` and it will become part of group `root`. This was part of my problem why I avoided using `virt-manager` as a normal user. So I fixed this and started `virt-manager` as a normal user.

I created the identical virtual machine but when a network window pops up it had different **(!)** options:

- **Userspace networking**
- **Specify shared device name**

I was unable to specify my interface `enx24f5a2f17b27` manualy with the second option so I chose a userspace networking.

[image]

Then I started the virtual machine which can browse the internet and also can the host machine. Both are assigned the IP **which is totaly different**. When I try to ping them ping doesn't work in any direction. Host, can't ping virtual machine and vice versa.

[image]

### Trying as a normal user (with bridge)

So now I first set up my my bridge precisely like I did in my first attempt as a `sudo user`:

sudo ip link add virtual_bridge type bridge
sudo ip link set dev virtual_bridge up
sudo ip link set dev enx24f5a2f17b27 down
sudo ip addr flush dev enx24f5a2f17b27
sudo ip link set dev enx24f5a2f17b27 up
sudo ip link set dev enx24f5a2f17b27 master virtual_bridge

so that I have:

```
ziga@ziga-laptop:~$ ip addr 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:85:08:3c:1a:59 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enx24f5a2f17b27: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virtual_bridge state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 24:f5:a2:f1:7b:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.64.100/24 brd 192.168.64.255 scope global enx24f5a2f17b27
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::26f5:a2ff:fef1:7b27/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: virtual_bridge: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 24:f5:a2:f1:7b:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::805f:cfff:feb6:ec91/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I started the `virt-manager` as a normal user and created the identical virtual machine. When a network window pops up it has same options than before:

- **Userspace networking**
- **Specify shared device name**

I was unable to specify my bridge `virtual_bridge` manualy with the second option because Qemu reports an internal eror:

[image]